# Can't read/open/ or do anything with a CSV file python 3.4 windows

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas, python-3.4

I am unable to open any CSV file produced by a program(I don't have full details of program), it comes out with file names like 266925.130314-88850999.word

The file is a csv, it opens in excel 2013 and all editors fine, I have tried opening with original file name, I have tried opening by changing extension from .word to .csv

Nothing works, I get the errors detailed below.

Sample Part of CSV

```
"tes","","2PT26","",4,7,"TEST","SHEEP AND STUFFF                  1kg","",1.1111,9.9999,1,0.000,2.6900,0.0000,0.000,
```

Full error Message in idle gui

```
>>> open('C:\Console2\edz\test.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
open('C:\Console2\edz\test.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Console2\\edz\test.csv'
```

Pandas error (not given full because its massive amount of text with traceback - can add if required)

```
OSError: File b'C:\\Console2\\edz\test.csv' does not exist
```

I have tested this file exists with

```
files = os.listdir("C:\Console2\edz")
print (files)

['report.csv', 'test.csv']
```

I can use EXACT same code with report.csv (this csv is a known working one not created by program) and it loads fine.

I do not understand why this file wont open, I have tried open/read_csv/read_excel, all produce same errors on both idle and pandas.

Pulling my hair out, please assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that Python uses [escapes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) in strings - `'\t'` is a tab character, so when that sequence appears in your path, it changes meaning (note how in the output, the other backslashes have been escaped). Python is looking for `'C:\Console2\edz    est.csv'`.

The best solution is to use forward slashes for paths - Python will do the correct thing, even under Windows.

```
open('C:/Console2/edz/test.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
```

You can also use a raw string (`r'C:\Console2\edz\test.csv'`) or escape your backslashes (`'C:\\Console2\\edz\\test.csv'`) - but the former can't deal with trailing backslashes, and the latter is hard to read and write.

Comment: I tried reversing the the slashes and got an error, not got it to hand, and oddly enough i can't replicate it, just tested reversing slashes and that works to. Many thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @Kuzen It must have been another change that caused the error - Python definitely supports the use of forward slashes for paths on Windows, it's a documented feature.

Comment: I dont doubt this, been frustrated with this for hours I have been trying alsorts. Maybe next time ill come here before i go mad :P

Answer (score 2):

`\t` is an escape character in python, try `\\t.`

```
C:\\Console2\\edz\\test.csv
```

you can  also prefix the string with  `r` 'raw string' before the path  `(r'C:\Console2\edz\test.csv'','r')`

Comment: this fixes the problem, but i dont think it has anything to do with the t, because i can load the files now fine just by adding \\ example pd.read_csv("C:\Console2\edz\\wtfevah.bob      either way all fixed, many thanks!!!